# ionic/angular select triggered element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i am new to ionic and angular and i can not do something simple like this.

i got an array, full of data. Which i am printing out in the view.
In every line, i insert a button with a star where the user can favorite this. What i want, is, that the star, which is clicked, should get a specific css class with a different style.
In html/jquery, i would just write:

```
onclick=myfunc(this)
```

and then in jquery:

```
function myfunc(elem){
    elem.addClass("newClass");
}
```

But in Angular, i need to write it like this:

```
<div class="">
  <button (click)="myfunc(elem)"><ion-icon name="ios-star-outline"></ion-icon></button>
</div>
```

And then in the ts file after the constructor:

```
save_printer(elem){
    elem.addClass("favorite");
}
```

How can i just add a class to the triggered button? i got 20 other buttons...

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the plunker solution

https://plnkr.co/edit/h8f71Pfo5FG7arwXfwsB

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let ele of tempArr; let i = index">
      {{ele.id}} &nbsp; 
      <span (click)="select(i)"> 
      <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" 
      [ngClass]="{'colorStar': ele.isUpvoted}"></i> </
      span>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  tempArr = [
    {
      id : 1,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 2,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 3,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 4,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 5,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 6,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 7,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 8,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 9,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
        {
      id : 10,
      isUpvoted : false
    },
    ]
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
  }

  select(index){
    console.log(index);
    this.tempArr[index].isUpvoted = !this.tempArr[index].isUpvoted;
    console.log(this.tempArr[index]);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: here, u create an array that has the id of the clicked element. But the point is, that the array could be 10, could be 20, maybe 40. It changes. I need a solution that only changes the triggered element.